# Hiding the toolbar of a Listview webpart through CSOM

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, client-object-model

I recently successfully added a web-part to the frontpage using the method from [Add Document Library XsltListViewWebPart using CSOM or web services](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90433/add-document-library-xsltlistviewwebpart-using-csom-or-web-services)

However, it seems impossible to disable the toolbar of this webpart. I have tried adding it to the webpart properties like

```
     <webParts>
         <webPart xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3'>
             <metaData>
             <type name='Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'/>
             <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
              </metaData>
              <data>
              <properties>
              <property name='DisableViewSelectorMenu' type='boolean'>true</property>
              <property name='InplaceSearchEnabled' type='boolean'>false</property>
              <property name='ListUrl' type='string'>ProjectInfo</property>
              <property name='Toolbar Type' type ='string'>None</property>
              <property name='MissingAssembly' type='string'>Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
              </properties>
              </data>
              </webPart>
           </webParts>
```

Or through the code using

```
WebPart importingWebPart = mgr.ImportWebPart(webPartXml).WebPart; // take webPartXml from above
WebPartDefinition wpDefinition = mgr.AddWebPart(importingWebPart, "Top", 1);
mgr.Context.Load(wpDefinition,d => d.Id); // Id of the hidden view which gets automatically created
mgr.Context.ExecuteQuery();
var viewId = wpDefinition.Id;

List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyLibrary");
View view = list.Views.GetById(viewId);
view.Toolbar = "<Toolbar Type='None'/>"
view.Update();
web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

But nothing works, it keeps happily displaying the toolbar. Yet if i try set the toolbar of a normal view this way, it works instantly.

[Edit]
It should be noted that i can modify all other settings of the view this way, just not the toolbar. I can sort, order, add viewfields

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The webpart doesn't has any property for setting Toolbar Type but the view does. You can use CSS or JSLink (postRender Handler) to remove/hide toolbar.

You CSOM seems to be updating the view in the list/library but not necessarily the view on your page.

Comment: Updating the query and viewfields of the view in this manner does work though. Its only the toolbar property that is disregarded