# how to add a Document library as a webpart to a sharepoint page using CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to add a Document Library as a webpart to a sharepoint page

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is posting in the same question here:

[Add Document Library XsltListViewWebPart using CSOM or web services](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90433/add-document-library-xsltlistviewwebpart-using-csom-or-web-services)

WebPart XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <webParts>
      <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
        <metaData>
          <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
          <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
        </metaData>
        <data>
          <properties>
            <property name="ListUrl" type="string">MyLibrary</property>
            <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
          </properties>
        </data>
      </webPart>
    </webParts>
```

CSOM Code:

```
    WebPart importingWebPart = mgr.ImportWebPart(webPartXml).WebPart; // take webPartXml from above
    WebPartDefinition wpDefinition = mgr.AddWebPart(importingWebPart, "Top", 1);
    mgr.Context.Load(wpDefinition,
        d => d.Id); // Id of the hidden view which gets automatically created
    mgr.Context.ExecuteQuery();
    var viewId = wpDefinition.Id;
    
    List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyLibrary");
    View view = list.Views.GetById(viewId);
    view.ViewFields.RemoveAll();
    view.ViewFields.Add("Title");
    view.ViewQuery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">Something Here</Value></Eq></Where>";
    view.RowLimit = 10;
    web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: I believe the most appropriate use of this CAML Query string is following the Value Type for Files, like this:

view.ViewQuery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\" /><Value Type=\"File\">some_file_name.extension</Value></Eq></Where>";

Comment: @AntonioLeonardo, yes. no problem as Title may be duplicated, but file name is unique, the CAML Query is optional, the key point to add library as web part is adding the xml definition in the page.

Comment: i/m able to add the doc library as a webpart on a page. but my actual requirement is to show items of a specific subfolder  as a webpart on the page and i'm creating a custom view and adding that view as a webpart..adding a web part is working but the custom view shows 0 items

Comment: this is query i/m using while creating the view

Comment: creationInfo.Query = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/><Value Type='Text'>Shared Documents/4 – Internal Reviews</Value></Contains></Where>";

Comment: changed the url to this /sites/RATP3_Migration/STI-Si-Dry-Etch/Shared Documents/4 – Internal Reviews  still its not working

Comment: What's the real library folder path, can you give a complete value so that we can test.

Comment: this is the path for a sub folder inside a sub folder inside a doc library  /sites/RATP3_Migration/STI-Si-Dry-Etch/Shared Documents/4 – Internal Reviews/Weekly Regular Update